# Problems while resizing laptop hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I am trying to reinstall windows 10 on my laptop and I decided to partition my HDD so I can have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 on dual boot I get the following error while booting from a USB with a Ubuntu  ISO and resizing the HDD. Any solutions?

```
Error resizing filesystem on /dev/sda2: Process reported exit code 1:
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
resize2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resuslted in short read
while trying to resize /dev/sda2
Please run 'e2fsck -fy /dev/sda2' to fix the filesystem
after the aborted resize operation.
(udisks-error-quark,0)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post so that the picture isn't sideways? Or better yet, include the error message as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Fixed!, I made it a text!

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions The partition shrink is done within Windows.

Comment: So I must remove the hdd, connect to a pc with windows, create the  partition, put the HDD back and the install windows 10 on the new partition?